# Confusing about Doolittle LU decomposition

Tags: math

According to Doolittle LU decomposition, a matrix could generally be decomposed as A = LU. Such decomposition exists when A is non-singular.

For below example, A = {{1,2,1}, {2,4,4}, {1,4,9}}.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxp2u.png)
Its determinant is -4 (non zero), and therefore matrices L and U exist.

However, when I follow the algorithm to factorize A,
[pseudo code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUSPZ.png)
it get u11 = 1, u12 = 2, u13 = 1, l21 = 2, l31 = 1, u22 = 0, u23 = 2,

Then, it fails to get l32 at this step. 4 = l31*u12+l32*u22

Also, if u22=0, it means det(U)=0 => det(A)=det(LU)=0. It contradicts to det(A)=-4!!!

Anyone can point out what I did wrong?